# How to move menu to left side of header on mobile

Tags: html, css, styling

I need to change the "hamburger" menu from the right side of the page to the left side. This is a live website [link](https://heteenzaamheidsfonds.nl). This webpage is build with the theme "Bulk". The icon has this styling:

```
.open-panel {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 22px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .shrink .open-panel {
        top: 14px;
    }
    .open-panel span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #000;
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    }
    .open-panel span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0px;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
        -moz-transform-origin: left center;
        -o-transform-origin: left center;
        transform-origin: left center;
    }
    .open-panel span:nth-child(2) {
        top: 9px;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
        -moz-transform-origin: left center;
        -o-transform-origin: left center;
        transform-origin: left center;
    }
    .open-panel span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 18px;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
        -moz-transform-origin: left center;
        -o-transform-origin: left center;
        transform-origin: left center;
    }
    .open-panel.open span:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        top: -2px;
        left: 3px;
    }
    .open-panel.open span:nth-child(2) {
        width: 0%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .open-panel.open span:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        top: 21px;
        left: 3px;
    }
```

And the logo on the left side has this styling:

```
.site-branding-logo {
    float: left;
}
.site-branding-logo a {
    border: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
}
.site-branding-logo img {
    max-height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

What lines do I need to change to get the menu on the left side and the icon on the right side?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement that, you have to do two things.

First, you need to update the hamburger style `.open-panel` class to be aligned on left (Currently, it's absolute position from the style so you can put it on left side using `left` attribute.)

Second, you need to update the logo icon link style `.site-branding-logo a` class to be aligned on right using `right` css attribute.

The following codes are the changes to implement them.

```
.open-panel {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 22px;  /* Replace `right` attribute to `left` attribute. */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

.site-branding-logo a {
    border: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, but the logo disappears. How can I troubleshoot this on mobile?

Comment: You mean, logo disappears on desktop? On mobile, is it fine? @hoofdtelefoon

Comment: No the logo disappears on mobile. Desktop is still working

Comment: Let's continue discussion on this chat room. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222228/css-issue @hoofdtelefoon

Answer (score 0):

Change `.site-branding-logo` css to have `float: right;` and remove `right: 22px` from `@media (max-width: 767px) .open-panel`.

If you don't want the logo to be on the left for other screen widths, you'll have to make sure there's a media query that only makes this applicable to the mobile screen size.